# proof for double summation formula

Tags: statistics, reference-request, time-series

I am looking for a proof for this formula:

$$\sum_{t=1}^N\sum_{s=1}^N f(t-s) = \sum_{k=-N+1}^{N-1} (N-|k|)f(k)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... and from $k = 1-N$ to $N-1$.

Hint: how many pairs $(s,t)$ are there with $t-s = k$?

Comment: yessss can i get the proof?

Comment: Did you try following the hint?  Where are you stuck?